# Is the FastCharacter website incorrectly calculating HP for my Sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, tools, hit-points, character-sheets

Based on my current knowledge, a Sorcerer with 14 Constitution (assuming you did HP averages) would start with:

Level 1: 6+2         = 8 hp
Level 6: 8+5x(4+2)   = 38 hp

But on fastcharacter.com using the same relevant stats (14 con, lvl 6, wild magic, sorcerer), [the character sheet shows 45 HP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0W1t.png).  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Nice character name - 'Heusten, we have a problem!'

Answer (score 22):

Creator of FastCharacter.com here. Y'all are right, sorcerers were getting d8 instead of d6 hit dice. Fixed it.

Answer (score 17):

Your HP calculations look correct to me. Sorcerers have d6 hit die, the average of which is 4, which gives me the same result you came up with (assuming a CON modifier of 2):

Level 6: (6+2)+5x(4+2) = 38 hp

The average of a d8 is 5. So if a Sorcerer had a d8 hit die:

Level 6: (8+2)+5x(5+2) = 45 hp

Therefore, my conclusion is that the fastcharacter.com website might be using a d8 by mistake.

Answer (score 11):

I made a 1st level wild magic teifling sorcerer at Fastcharacter.com, and got 10 HP with 14 Con.

Fastcharacter.com is using a d8 for the sorcerer instead of a d6

Comment: I find this useful for having actually gone and creating the character yourself. Just to be sure I would instead say that you created a "1st level wild magic sorcerer"

Answer (score 5):

Your calculation is correct, the site is wrong. It looks like they have used the calculation for d8s instead of d6s.

I would assume that if you de-leveled to 1st you would see 10hp

Comment: Clarifying questions should be asked as a comment on the question, not as part of your answer.

Comment: @V2Blast it wasn't a clarifying question, it was an assumption about a tool I have not used